# For loop iteration increment value by 1.why?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Why `k` value is one increment when it should stop to 1 in first iteration and 3 in second iteration and so on?

```
public class pattern6 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int i, j, k, space = 5;
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < space; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            space--;
            for (k = i; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++)
                System.out.print(k);
            System.out.print("k value:" + k); // k value is incremented by 1
            if (i > 1)
                for (int temp = k - 2; temp >= i; temp--) {
                    System.out.print(temp);
                }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
 run:
     1k value:2
    23k value:42
   345k value:643
  4567k value:8654
 56789k value:108765
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Why k value is 2,4,6,8 etc?

Comment: Please paste code as text, not image links.

Comment: Hi @Mhadasavi, could you post code instead of screenshot into the question?

Comment: sorry for not proper formatting as i m newbie here.i will paste code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.... I can see the output is already increased by 1 as your expectation. It is not 2,4,6,8 as you mentioned:

```
     1k value:2
    23k value:42
   345k value:643
  4567k value:8654
 56789k value:108765


        for (k = i; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++)
            System.out.print(k);
        System.out.print("k value:" + k); // k value is increment by 1
```

If you want the code print the corresponding value one by one, you can clearly state that:

```
for (k = i; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++){
    System.out.println("temp k value:" + k); // k value is increment by 1
}
System.out.println ("final K value:"+k);
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop stops when k is 2, 4, 6, 8 etc and it doesn't rollback the increment.

After the loop, k has the value which caused the loop to stop otherwise it should still be looping.

Comment: u r right @Peter . thanks, but question is why is k print 2 when loop stop after k=1.

Comment: @Upkar You are right, it stops **after** `k==1` and 2 is after 1.